# Laptop doesn't wake up after going to sleep

Tags: debian, hibernate, plasma

I run Debian with KDE Plasma on Xorg. I have tried all the main ways on the internet to properly wake the computer after it going to sleep. But whatever I do, it doesn't work.

- I have gone to the Power Management too, but I didn't find anything that I could change there.
- This problem is there even if the laptop lid is closed or not. If the laptop lid is closed, and I open it, it gets frozen (like a very dim screen with a mouse pointer is there, so dim as if it was about to turn on the monitor but froze). And if the laptop lid is not closed and the computer goes to sleep, any key I press doesn't work.
- I have backlit keyboard on my laptop... The light comes up but nothing on the screen. Even the mouse (trackpad) won't work.
- I have to manually every time press the power button and shut off the laptop and start it again.

I am kind of new to linux, so if any information is required from my side and it is a command, I would appreciate the command given as well. Or if it isn't a command, I would like to have the steps of getting that information

Comment: What processor do you have?

Comment: Intel i5-11300H [4 core, 8 thread]

If you want to know the laptop itself: Mi Notebook Pro [https://www.mi.com/in/product/mi-notebook-pro/] 16 gb RAM